# Google Apps Script with Forms: Release mark and feedback after submission

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-classroom

In Google Apps Script, I can use the code below to create a rudimentary quiz:

```
function init() {
  var quizForm = FormApp.create("Test quiz");

  quizForm.setIsQuiz(true);
  quizForm.setCollectEmail(false);
  quizForm.setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false);

  var item = quizForm.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  item.setTitle("Test question");
  item.setChoices([
    item.createChoice("A choice", true),
    item.createChoice("Another choice", false)]);

  item.setPoints(1);
  item.setFeedbackForIncorrect(
    FormApp.createFeedback().setText("It was the other one.").build());
}
```

I would like the respondents to **see their marks and any feedback as soon as they submit their answers**. However, the settings default to what you can see in the image below, and I see no way in the documentation to programmatically set the choices under "Release mark" and "Respondent can see".

Does anyone know if/how this can be achieved?

[image: Go]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Release grade immediately after submission - how to do using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471090/release-grade-immediately-after-submission-how-to-do-using-apps-script)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you @Jescanellas and sorry for missing the duplicate.